# cookies not being saved/read correctly

Tags: php, cookies

I've made a little PHP website which works in three different languages. These languages can either be set through a $_GET or a $_COOKIE with $_GET being the first to be checked so it can overwrite a cookie if needed. If I determine the language I need, I include a file which holds all my translations and set a cookie for future use. The code looks something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {

    // if language in $_SET is English, load english translation and set a cookie for the future.
    if ($_GET['language'] == 'EN') { 
        setcookie('language','EN', time()+31536000);
        include 'tekstenEngels.php';

    // if language in $_SET is French, load french translation and set a cookie for the future.
    } elseif ($_GET['language'] == 'FR') { 
        setcookie('language','FR', time()+31536000);
        include 'tekstenFrans.php';

    // lastly if language in $_SET is Dutch, load Dutch translation and set a cookie for the future
    } else { 
        setcookie('language','NL', time()+31536000);
        include 'tekstenNederlands.php';
    }

// the same but for cookies in case this isn't the first visit
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['language'])) { 
    if ($_COOKIE['language'] == 'EN') {
        include 'tekstenEngels.php';
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['language'] == 'FR') {
        include 'tekstenFrans.php';
    } else {
        include 'tekstenNederlands.php';
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine on my locahost but it doesn't seem to write/read the cookies correctly when used on my webserver. Any ideas what I could be missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your php.ini file allows cookies.
you may want to explore [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/it/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) if not.

Comment: Cookies are enabled. Sometimes my code works like a charm and it remembers everything correctly while on other attempts I need to refresh my page for the code to be executed succesfully. It's really driving me crazy because I can't seem to find the problem here.

Comment: To track it down, try to strip the code to the minimum. Eg: only the posted code just followed by a print_r($_COOKIE) without any other conditions, if and elses.
If this still is unreliable/random it may be a server performance issue. Sometimes [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/it/function.ob-start.php) can solve these ghostly bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is identical, but the outcome is different, it points to the configuration of the webserver. Create the following file, called `phpinfo.php`:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Browse to it on your localhost and on your webserver, comparing the results of any of the cookie/session related configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question as a guest. While clearing all my cookies to speed up looking up my websites' cookie, I got 'logged out' of this website so I cannot update my question anymore.

I had 2 different pages which used almost the same php code for checking the language: a "home" page (index.php) and a "more info" page (info.php). The only difference was the redirection: when setting the language on the index.php page, it pointed the user back to the index.php page while the info.php page pointed the user back to the info.php page.

For some, still unknown reason, when changing the language on the index.php page made the cookies save correctly while doing the same thing on the info.php page didn't work, I had to refresh the page there for it to work which I really don't understand as it's using the EXACT SAME code.

However, when changing the language code in the info.php page to redirect to the index.php instead of the info.php page, it suddenly all worked.

Wow. I really don't see any logic in this.

This problem is fixed, though I don't know how... I'm guessing it has something to do with the server configuration but I don't have any access to this so I can't make any changes there.

This question may be closed.